# Ubuntu 20.04.1 fresh install, wget and ping commands don't work?

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, wget, ping

Something odd is happening in my new installation of Ubuntu 20.04.1. The internet works fine - I can browse websites through Firefox. However, running a `wget` command or `ping www.google.com` just hangs there - as if the terminal cannot see the internet connection. For example:

```
 wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-27.1.tar.gz
--2020-09-23 23:19:33--  https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-27.1.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)... 2001:470:142:3::b, 209.51.188.20
Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)|2001:470:142:3::b|:443...
```

... and it just hangs there forever. However, `git clone <repo>` works fine! Any idea what might be the issue here?

Comment: Same here, i have a VPS with fresh ubuntu 20.04 :'(

Comment: Solved in my VPS changin MTU  `sudo ip link set dev wlp3s0 mtu 1438`